# Can't delete record when calling Stored Procedure from Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures, package

I have the following stored procedure inside a package:

```sql
PROCEDURE DELETE_RECORD(serial IN NUMBER, code IN NUMBER, brand IN VARCHAR2, response OUT VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM CWPESME.cwpesme_campaign_subsc
    WHERE 
    sku = serial
    AND id = code
    AND mfg = brand;
    COMMIT;
        response := 'SUCCESS';
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        response := 'FAILURE '||SQLERRM;
END DELETE_RECORD;
```

This is how I call it from a web service:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public string del_record(int serial, int code, string brand)
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "MyPackage.DELETE_RECORD";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("sku", OracleType.Number, 38).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters["sku"].Value = serial;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("id", OracleType.Number, 38).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters["id"].Value = code;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("mfg", OracleType.VarChar, 250).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters["mfg"].Value = brand;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("response", OracleType.VarChar, 550).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string result = cmd.Parameters["response"].Value.ToString();
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string result = cmd.Parameters["response"].Value.ToString();
                return (result != string.Empty) ? result : "[FAILURE] " + ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to remove the record if I call the stored procedure directly, but unable to do so when calling from a web service. I can however `SELECT` and `UPDATE` in this way. What's happening?

Comment: What account is the web service running as (SO doesn't need to know this) and does it have permission to delete (but does need this)?

Comment: Shouldn't cmd.CommandText be = to "DELETE_RECORD"?

Comment: @tonyriddle thanks; I've corrected the placeholder

Comment: @AustinSalonen I've tried running the Web Service using both IIS7's default user as well as Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET Web Development Server's user. The database user has permission to delete.

Comment: What does "unable to do so" mean?  Do you get an error?  What specific error are you getting?

Comment: Check for the account that calls the stored procedure. It may not have the appropriate permission to perform the delete.

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak it's not throwing any exception, it always returns 'SUCCESS' but when I check the database table, nothing has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the code; the user was re-checked and granted all privileges over the table and now is able to delete rows.